# Empty meta-box returns publishdate if no value is set?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, post-meta, events

I have no idea why this would/could happen.

I have a custom metabox for an "event_end_date" set for a custom-post-type. If I leave this field blank it always puts out the publish-date of the post itself?

I use the [Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/issues/208) library like this …

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id'         => 'event_info_optional',
    'title'      => 'Optional',
    'pages'      => array( 'wr_event'),
    'context'    => 'normal',
    'show_names' => true,
    'priority' => 'core',
    'fields'     => array(

        array(
            'name' => 'End time of event',
            'id'   => $prefix . 'event_end_time',
            'type' => 'text_time',
        )
    ),
);
```

And I save the value like this …

```
$wr_event_end_date = isset($_POST['wr_event_end_date']) ? $_POST['wr_event_end_date'] : '';
$event_end_date = new DateTime($wr_event_end_date);
update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_end_date", $event_end_date->getTimestamp());
```

And I query the value like this …

```
function get_event_end_date($post) {
   $date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_end_date');
   if ( !empty( $date[0] ) ) {
       //only if a value is saved I return the value
       return $date[0];
   }
}
```

This works for all other custom fields. Just for my event-end-date it doesn't. If I leave the field empty in my backend and save the post, the post itself always shows the publish-date of the post as event-end-date.

Why and how could this `get_event_end_date()` function return the publish-date of the post if I leave it empty. If I set a value to the field it works fine, but if I leave it empty I don't want the function to return anything.

**UPDATE**

```
        // End-event-date
        /*$wr_event_end_date = isset($_POST['wr_event_end_date']) ? $_POST['wr_event_end_date'] : '';
        $event_end_date = new DateTime($wr_event_end_date);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_end_date", $event_end_date->getTimestamp());*/

        if ( isset($_POST['wr_event_end_date']) ) {
            die('this is getting called even though the field is submitted blank');
            $event_end_date = new DateTime($_POST['wr_event_end_date']);
            update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_end_date", $event_end_date->getTimestamp());
        } else {
            update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_end_date", "");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm half asleep here  so correct me if I am wrong here but it looks to me like you are saving the publish date of the post each time you save the post,

```
$wr_event_end_date = isset($_POST['wr_event_end_date']) ? $_POST['wr_event_end_date'] : '';
$event_end_date = new DateTime($wr_event_end_date);
update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_end_date", $event_end_date->getTimestamp());
```

This `-> $event_end_date->getTimestamp()` being the culprit.

So regardless of your variable `$wr_event_end_date` value being set or not, your meta value is being assigned via `getTimestamp()` because firstly there is no conditional statement that checks for the existence of your,

```
$_POST['wr_event_end_date']
```

which if `FALSE` will instead revert to `''` (no value) which is then passed to your

```
new DateTime($wr_event_end_date);
```

Secondly, because

```
new DateTime( //is now empty here );
```

your

```
getTimestamp()
```

returns the current time stamp of the post.

## UPDATE

You should still use the `text_date` custom field, example:

```
array(
    'name' => 'Test Date Picker',
    'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
    'id'   => $prefix . 'test_textdate',
    'type' => 'text_date',
),
```

...instead of using a timestamp especially if you have no reason to use a timestamp other than to convert it back to a regular date format because WordPress has inbuilt functions for handling date and time formatting.

Here is an example;

```
global $post;
$text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_test_textdate', true );
$text = date('d F Y', $text); 
echo $text;
    //prints 25 September 2012 for example
```

I've made sure to test this library to ensure it is in fact outputting results correctly and it sure is.

Comment: Oh, wow, this must be it. But I'm pretty new to php, how can I make sure it is only save if there is a value in the box?

Comment: Where are you placing your `update_post_meta` function and are you trying to save values from a front end form? If you're not, **then** you really don't need to have an `update_post_meta` function because the meta box library you are using **handles the saving of fields and their values** when in the post edit screen. So instead you should only enter a value if you want to, if not, then the field will remain blank until you provide a value.

Comment: Well, I'm kind of confused now. I don't need to save the details of the meat-boxes? I didn't know that the lib handles this as well … see a snippet of my code … http://cl.ly/code/2F2B2R102B3P … I save all the details for my custom post type with `update_post_meta()` and retrieve them via a custom `get_event_something()` function. Can you provide a little update on how I really do that with the library? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unless you have the need to do something else with the data prior to saving it **WHICH** does not consist of **simply saving it as you entered it within the post edit screen**, then I do not see the need for a custom function hooked onto the `save_post` action because the library handles the saving of data for you already. Refer to [init.php](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/blob/master/init.php#L398). Your custom function to retrieve the post meta is on the other hand **OK** because it may serve your need to customize output or simplify a verbose process.

Comment: I suggest temporarily removing (commenting out) your `save_details` function as shown in your link above and experiment with the meta box in question to see how the library natively handles the the input data for you by default.

Comment: Ok, thank you. However the real problem in my case might be that I `'type' => 'text_date',` as the input for my `event_end_date` field and then I'm converting it to a timestamp! And I need to convert it to a timestamp because I need to parse it as a german date on the frontend. I know there is also a field type of the library that provides a timestamp. However I want my backend to use german date formatting when I select a date in the date-picker. When saving the date I want to convert it to a timestamp (because I need this value for sorting stuff) and inside my `get_event_end_date()` function

Comment: … I need to convert this timestamp back to a german date like "25. September 2012" … And that's why in this case I need the `save_details()` function for this particular field. I just need to find a way not to create and save a timestamp when the value of the input is empty. Does that sound complicated?

Comment: @mathiregister Please refer to my update. You are going about this the long way round. Revert back to using `'type' => 'text_date'` and then use the in built WordPress Date handling functions to format your output as desired. (link to Codex resource in answer above).

Comment: Ok, thank you but I still don't get it. Please bear with me. I do have it set as `text_date` … but I'm converting it to a timestamp when I save it to the database! I need to do so, because I'm sorting my events by this timestamp and can't do it with a fully formatted date. I completely got rid of my `update_post_meta()` function for the "event_end_date" but nothing is getting saved to the database automatically!? Are you sure this is saved automatically. I'm inspecting ma database table after I save the event-end-date field but nothing is in the db.

Comment: And what I don't get either is when I'm testing for `isset($_POST['wr_event_end_date'])?` inside my `save_details()` function and call a `die('event-end-date is set!`);` and leave the field blank it still dies! So even though the field is empty (and nothing should be set to the field) the condition is true! Why is that? Nothing is getting saved to the database but the condition is true – see my update above!

Comment: @mathiregister I've removed strtotime() from the $text variable in my example above. This formats the date in a human readable form. So continue storing your values as `'type' => 'text_date_timestamp'` then (as you wish), then when running your query you sort by the meta_key you have set for that value. This works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5963/discussion-between-userabuser-and-mathiregister)